# Tables with capital letters not visible in Docker for Windows

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-for-windows

I'm using Docker Toolbox for now. I have project with database that has both standard (lower-case tables) and also upper case. For example: `migrations` and `T_EXPORT`.

Using Docker Toolbox everything is fine but I would like to switch to Docker for Windows and here's the problem - when I run the same project on Docker for Windows in database there are only visible lower-case tables (`migrations`) but upper-case are not visible at all. Obviously this causes that site is not working and those tables cannot be managed.

When I switch again to Docker Toolbox all tables are again visible and everything is working fine.

I would like to point that the whole project is in the same place. I don't copy project files anywhere - I'm using exact same project files (including database files) and only switch between Docker Toolbox and Docker for Windows so in theory everything should work.

The question - is there any option I should add to `docker-composer.yaml` to make it work or maybe this is a bug in Docker for Windows that should be solved by Docker team?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem in the `Docker` version or the `Database` version, I've encountered that is when I create `Table` with **uppercase** and **lowercase** letters example `HrEmployee` (there I use `MariadDB10.2` and `Ubuntu 16.04`) and then I move to `Windows 10` and use **Navicat** as a 3rd party and what happened was all my tables I wanted move to Navicat, and I found the problem was I was using `MariDB10.1` and when I **upgraded** to `MariaDB10.2`, the problem was `resolved`, I don't know if it was a problem from the database